# non-string key Missing field in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

For migration I have used the following couchbase query

```
INSERT INTO `bucket`
(KEY _k, VALUE _v, OPTIONS {"expiration": ttl})
SELECT REPLACE(META().id, "2_", "3_", 1) _K, META(_v).expiration AS ttl
from `bucket` _v
where _v._class="classname"
AND META().id LIKE "2_%";
```

While running getting the following error

```
{
"code": 5070,
"msg": "Cannot INSERT non-string key Missing field or index _k. of type value.missingValue."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was different cases(lower and upper) used in different places. changing _k to small case solved the problem.